# Replacing all negative elements with zero eigen3 c++

Tags: c++, eigen3

As said I want to replace all < 0 elements in a eigen3 matrix in C++ with zero in most efficient manner.

I check that there are negative elements using:

```
(result.array() < 0).any()
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A nicer and more efficient way than your proposed method would be to use the [`select`](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1DenseBase.html#aaaed9ab0c7a20c689017542e40d1ef6e) method.

```
result = (result.array() < 0).select(0, result);
```

Comment: There are three overloads for the `select` method. This example corresponds to [this overload](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1DenseBase.html#title106).

Comment: I have a similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74438460/change-values-of-non-contiguous-entries-in-a-rcppeigen-vector. What if I would like to replace negative entries with another vector? For example `result = (result.array() < 0).select(vect1, vect2);` where the size of `vect1` is the number of negative entries in `result` and the size of `vect2` is the number of nonnegative entries in `result`. I am wondering if this works. The difficulty here is that `result`, `vect1`, and `vect2` do not have the same dimension. What to do in this case?

Answer (score 1):

I found a way:
Create a matrix of zeros of same shape,

```
zero_matrix.setZero();
```

And find coeff wise maximum between zero matrix and your matrix.

```
result = result.array().max(zero_matrix.array());
```