# Find the index in a matrix meeting some conditions in Rcpp Eigen

Tags: rcpp, eigen3

I have a 2-dim matrix, and I would like to truncate all elements less than some threshold to 0. It would be simple to realize in base R with code `X[X < 0.1] <- 0`. But how can I realize it efficiently in Rcpp with Eigen3 if X is of type MatrixXd. Thanks!

Comment: This seems relevant / duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40445701/replacing-all-negative-elements-with-zero-eigen3-c